# Android EditText Search Issues on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I am trying to implement a Search feature on my recyclerView. It is working but

I'm facing few issues.

1.When I click on the editText, My recycler view goes blank.Only when I start typing the recycler view is updated.

2.if I close the keyboard to type(I press the back button )My recycler view goes empty.
Here's my code:

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    filter(s.toString());
                }
            });


 private void filter(String text) {



    if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        filteredList.addAll(followLists);
    }
    else {
        for (followList item : followLists) {
            if (item.Name.toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }

        }


    }
    followListRecyclerAdapter.filterList(filteredList);
}
```

On my Adapter:

```
 public void filterList(ArrayList<followList> filteredList) {
    followLists = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `afterTextChanged` and inspect the value of `s` each time. Dunno why keyboard closing would cause that to be called, but check it out with debugging